# Internal Azure ASE Inboud/Outbound Traffic To Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-app-service-envrmnt, network-security-groups

I have a logic app sitting in an internal ase which is also sitting behind an azure app gateway. The logic app does not automatically "fetch" via the run trigger I assume due to some traffic constraints utilizing the office365 api connection on an internal ase. The Logic App has a "when a new email arrives" trigger based on a specific subject line but this never triggers. Is the best way to accomplish this is to utilize a NSG to allow inbound/outbound traffic to the various list of ip address etc for Office365? Are there any pre-existing service tags I can use on the NSG?

Answer (score 1):

As per [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/howto-service-tags),  you can use services tags in network security group. As you are using logic app which is on internal ASE, need to add inbound and output security rules as mentioned in the above document.

Add outbound rule as shown in below image,
[image]

Add inbound rule also as shown in below pic,
[image]

Reference [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/network-security-groups-overview#security-rules)

Comment: Thanks @Vijaya. Are you stating that the SignalIR service tag is required for office 365 to function properly or more so around the process? I have noticed the AzureConnectors service tag as well which states "allow office azure connectors".